# shell command with options from php

Tags: php, shell, command, iconv

I have this code:

```
$codif ="file --mime-encoding -b inputfile.txt";
$codif = shell_exec($codif);
$encode = "iconv --from-code=$codif --to-code=UTF-8 --output=tempfile.txt inputfile.txt";
```

I have tried

```
shell_exec($encode); //1
exec($encode); //2
system($encode); //3
```

And I have this just to see what's the generated command:

```
echo $encode;
```

Which outputs this:

```
iconv --from-code=iso-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 --output=tempfile.txt inputfile.txt
```

The problem is that with either of the three forms of executing the command I get next error:

```
sh: 2: --to-code=UTF-8: not found
```

While executing the output command at the shell works perfectly.
I have also tried changing the `--to-code=UTF-8` to `-t UTF-8` with the same results.
So the questions are, what am I doing wrong and how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a new line at the end of the $codif variable, which messes things up.
That needs to be stripped out some way.
You can try this for example:

```
$codif ="file --mime-encoding -b inputfile.txt|tr -d '\n'";
$codif = shell_exec($codif);
```

Piping  output of `file` command to `tr -d "\n"` will remove the new line. You can of course remove that in the php code aswell.

Comment: Yes, you hit it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$encode` var to:

`iconv -f $codif -t UTF-8 --output=tempfile.txt inputfile.txt`

To output something like:

`iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 --output=tempfile.txt inputfile.txt`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you before, yes changing to a fix value makes it work, but I need the encode detection part, so this is what is failing.

Comment: Anyway I tried also changing `--from-code=` to `-f` which doesn't work, but changing `$codif` variable to a fix value `iso-8859-1` makes it work. So the problem seems to be getting the variable value on time to execute de commad.